# ES index mapping has "query" parameter

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

One of my indices had this mapping:

```
"mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "count": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "currency": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 16
                        }
                    }
                },
                "query": {
                    "properties": {
                        "match_all": {
                            "type": "object"
                        },
                        "range": {
                            "properties": {
                                "hour": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "gte": {
                                            "type": "date"
                                        },
                                        "lt": {
                                            "type": "date"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I couldn't understand why was it so I created a new index and made sure it didn't have this **query** fluff in it. After ensuring that the new index's mapping was fine, I started the reindex process, but after some time, I again noticed this:

```
"mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "count": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "currency": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "index_options": "freqs"
                },
                "query": {
                    "properties": {
                        "match_all": {
                            "type": "object"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The **query** part is changed, but it's still there and I am not sure what's causing it to be like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't set `"dynamic": "strict"` in your mapping, your mapping will be allowed to be spread by indexing new data. You have inserted the query section as data to your index. When you reindex data, all data will be transferred to the new index and you still see that post and changing mapping. To not have this, you need to set `"dynamic": "strict"` in your mapping or try not to index such documents.

Comment: Thank you. I can try that, but I don't understand why it appeared in the first place

Comment: Setting dynamic to strict will only prevent the mapping from being modified, but doesn't solve the source problem.

Comment: For example, you wanted to search for something through kibana. By choosing POST method instead of GET and not inserting `_search` at the end, you say that I want to insert such data and because you don't have strict mapping it will be inserted.

Comment: Ahh makes sense. Okay, but in my case now, how can I get rid of this. Using "dynamic": "strict" on the new index and then reindexing from old to new will fix this problem, right?

Comment: Yes, Set `conflicts` to `proceed` as well in your reindex API calling.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually the result of posting the query to an endpoint different than the `_search` endpoint.

For instance, if you run this, you're going to create a new document **and modify the mapping of your index**

```
POST index/_doc
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Queries must always be sent to the `_search` endpoint:

```
POST index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```